# How do I get my Etherpad changes to show up?

Tags: java, etherpad

I change files like /etherpad/trunk/infrastructure/ace/www/ace2_inner.js and then run /etherpad/trunk/etherpad/rebuildjar.sh and yet when I run it again everything looks the same. Is there a trick I'm missing?

I've also tried running rebuildjar.sh with clearcache to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Look at bin/build.sh and track down which scripts are called directly and which scripts are called via subscripts. The whole thing is a mess :/

Answer (score 0):

ace2_inner is perhaps one of the autogenerated .js files? What you need to do is read the first 10-20 lines of every source code file before you edit it, to make sure you're not editing an autogenerated file.
If you don't know the structure, then use bin/build.sh every time until you learn how to handle the source code. (This advice isn't actually etherpad-specific :)
And then make sure you've STOPPED all etherpad servers before starting up a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Always clear the browser cache properly after changing the etherpad files. Otherwise none of your changes will show up.